# locate element in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium to navigate a webpage which has a link named "Edit", using WebDriver (just recently switched from RC to WebDriver). I want to click on the link but the testcase always fails with the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Edit"}
```

When inspecting the element with Firebug I got the following HTML:

```
<a href="/00kn00000039X4j/e?retURL=%2F006n0000002BuKq" class="actionLink" title="Edit - Record 1 - Collaborator - Concurrent User License (Includes 1 year Maintenance)">Edit</a>
```

This is the Java which attempts to click the link:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Mail"));
```

I can see that the element is present on screen but still, the test case fails.

Does anyone know what I might be missing here or an alternative way to find the link element?

Comment: Please, provide html source of this link

Comment: Provide sample html.

Answer (score 1):

The link text is `Edit` not `Mail`

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Edit"));
```